# Having trouble combining two images using UIGraphics, images not correctly positioned

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to make a simple app that combines the camera overlay with the photo that is taken in UIImagePicker. In this example I want to combine the overlay view of bear ears with the photo.

```
- (IBAction)pushTakePhoto:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

    //create overlay UIView
    UIImage *bearEars = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bearEars"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bearEars];

    UIView *camerOverlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];
    [camerOverlayView addSubview:imageView];


    [picker setCameraOverlayView:camerOverlayView];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

the code above creates the overlay, this works fine. The code below combines the images:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //first we flip the image
    UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:chosenImage.CGImage scale:chosenImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
    chosenImage=flippedImage;

    //now we need to add the ears


    //get pics
    UIImage *backgroundImage = chosenImage;
    UIImage *watermarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bearEars"];

    //start a workspace
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.size);
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];
    //position seems off for some reason
    [watermarkImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    chosenImage=result;


    self.finalImageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

When I combine the images however the bearEars overlay is not positioned at (0,0) but instead in the middle of the final image. I'm not sure why this is happening. I just want it to overlay the images like in the camera view. Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the image is centered because you are using the same rect size in drawInRect method for both images.
Try to change size from backgroundImage.size to watermarkImage.size for watermarkImage:

```
[watermarkImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, watermarkImage.size.width, watermarkImage.size.height)];
```

EDITED:

To do the correct size for watermarkImage you need to find a scale size - a difference in size from image in preview from the final image. You can do this by dividing width of the backgroundImage to the width of the self.view

```
CGFloat scale = backgroundImage.size.width / self.view.frame.size.width;
```

Then you can use this value during drawing watermarkImage:

```
[watermarkImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, watermarkImage.size.width * scale, watermarkImage.size.height * scale)];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that, it just makes the watermarkImage much smaller and not the correct size

Comment: I've expanded the answer, hope it helps